# Minimization through lmfit

Tags: python, numpy, minimize, minimization, lmfit

I want to estimate the value of x. So here is the code which is working for me as I make x my parameter.

`

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from lmfit import Parameters, minimize
from numpy import exp, linspace, random


def gaussian(x, amp, cen, wid):
    return amp * exp(-(x-cen)**2 / wid)


x = linspace(-10, 10, 101)
data = gaussian(x, 2.33, 0.21, 1.51) + random.normal(0, 0.2, x.size)
Model = gaussian(x, 2.33,0.21,1.51)

plt.plot(x, data, label = 'data')
plt.plot(x, Model, label = 'Model')
plt.legend()
plt.grid(True)
plt.show()


d = 50
print ("\nThe data value at {} is {}\n".format(0, data[0+d]))

params = Parameters()
params.add('x', value =-3)    


def objective(params, amp, cen, wid, data):
    x = params['x']
    m = gaussian(x, amp, cen, wid)
    return data - m


result = minimize(objective, params=params, args=(2.33, 0.21, 1.51,data[d]))
print(result.params)
```

`

So here my parameter is x.
In my objective function I am giving the value of data at 50, which corresponds to x at 0. 
I am initializing my parameter's initial value to be something close to 0, so I'm setting it to -3.

When you print the result.params you see that it converges to the 0.

Now if I make amp cen and wid as parameters, it gives me an error

**TypeError: objective() argument after * must be an iterable, not numpy.float64**

`

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from lmfit import Parameters, minimize
from numpy import exp, linspace, random

def gaussian(x, amp, cen, wid):
    return amp * exp(-(x-cen)**2 / wid)    

x = linspace(-10, 10, 101)
data = gaussian(x, 2.33, 0.21, 1.51) + random.normal(0, 0.2, x.size)
Model = gaussian(x, 2.33,0.21,1.51)

plt.plot(x, data, label = 'data')
plt.plot(x, Model, label = 'Model')
plt.legend()
plt.grid(True)
plt.show()


d = 50
print ("\nThe data value at {} is {}\n".format(0, data[0+d]))

params = Parameters()
params.add('x', value =-5)
params.add('amp', value = 1)
params.add('cen', value = 1)
params.add('wid', value = 1)

def objective(params, data):    
    x = params['x']
    amp = params['amp']
    cen = params['cen']
    wid = params['wid']

    m = gaussian(x, amp, cen, wid)
    return data - m


result = minimize(objective, params=params, args=( data[d]))
print(result.params)
```

`

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Well, basically you're asking to alter 4 different variables (`x`, `amp`, `cen`, and `wid`) to match 1 data point: `data[d]`. The error message you get:

```
......
    out = self.userfcn(params, *self.userargs, **self.userkws)
TypeError: objective() argument after * must be an iterable, not numpy.float64
```

is the fit telling you that the return value of the objective function must be an array, not a single floating-point number.

A fit with 4 variables requires at least 4 `y` values. Otherwise, you could change `x`, `amp`, `cen`, and `wid` over a continuous range of values to have `gaussian(x, amp, can, wid)` match `data[d]` -- the problem does not have a single solution.

If the idea is to find a value of `x` for which a Gaussian function takes a single particular `y` value, you can do that using "root-finding" -- at least to the extent possible given that there will at least 2 `x` values for every valid `y` value.

To do that, you could use `scipy.optimize.root` to find the value of where `gaussian(x, amp, cen, wid) - data[d]` is zero:

```
def objective(x, amp, cen, wid, yval):
     return gaussian(x, amp, cen, wid) - yval

from scipy.optimize import root
init_x = 0.0  # initial guess for `x` value
result = root(objective, init_x, (100, 1.22, 2.5, data[50]))
print(result.x)
```